# jQuery target id inside iframe and alert

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

My code is like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>TODO</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="btn">
      <button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="iframebox">
      <iframe id="messageiframe">
        <html>

        <head>
          <title>test</title>
        </head>

        <body>
          <div id="textpreview">
            <p id="pre">some text</p>
          </div>
        </body>

        </html>
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I am trying to target `id="textpreview"` inside iframe using jQuery. I can successfully target any id outside iframe but unable to target inside iframe.

My jQuery code is:

```
$('#clickme').on('click', function() {
  if ($("#textpreview").length > 0) {
    alert("success");
  }
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your jquery plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "contents()"

```
$("#messageiframe").contents().find("#textpreview")
```

https://api.jquery.com/contents/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>TODO</title>
  </head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="btn">
      <button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div class="iframebox">
      <iframe id="messageiframe">
        <html>

        <head>
          <title>test</title>
        </head>

        <body>
          <div id="textpreview">
            <p id="pre">some text</p>
          </div>
        </body>

        </html>
      </iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
<script>

$('#clickme').on('click', function() {

  if ($("#textpreview").has("pre")) {
    alert("success");
  }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Check whether it has the id.